# Why isn't this simple if statement working?

Tags: jquery

I want to show/hide the section depending on the window width. I tried:

```
$(function(){
    "use strict";

    if($(window).width() > 600) {
        $("section").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("section").show();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<section>
    <ol>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

But im not seeing the section hide. What am I doing wrong?

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jLx5V/

Comment: Well for one you're doing `.remove()` instead of `.hide()` in your fiddle and a removed element will never come back. Secondly, you're only executing it once. Do you mean to check this on `window.resize`?

Comment: your fiddle is different from the code here, but it is absolutely not being shown on widths greater than 600. set it to 900 and you'll see it appear. are you wanting it to animate the hide/show instead?

Comment: Works fine for me... you do know it will only run once, when the script is first loaded right?

Comment: The if statement is working just fine. This is a logic error, your if statement only runs once, therefore when the window resizes, it isn't re-checking the width.

Comment: Two things - first you can do it with CSS media queries. Second, you want to bind this to `$(window).resize(` and not `$(document).ready(` so it reacts to change.

Comment: You're probably better off using media queries to do this kind of logic - That way, if the user resizes the window, the section will appear/disappear accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement itself is fine. My guess is that the window is more than 600px wide when you first go to the page. You haven't hooked the `resize` event, so you're not re-running that code when the window size changes.

Here's what that would look like: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLx5V/7/)

```
$(function(){
    "use strict";

    resize();
    $(window).resize(resize);

    function resize() {
        $("section").toggle($(window).width() <= 600);
    }
});
```

That does this:

1. Defines a `resize` function that shows or hides all `section` elements based on the window's width (shows them if it's 600px wide or less, hides them if more).
2. Calls `resize` on DOM ready (which is when you were originally calling it).
3. Hooks it up to the `resize` event on the `window` so it gets called again if the user resizes the window.
4. Uses `toggle(flag)`, which is shorthand for "if flag is true show, otherwise hide."

Comment: Apologies for the earlier error where I was hiding when I should have been showing and vice-versa. Fixed now.

Comment: no problem! also do I need to initially define the `resize()` method? it seems to work without it, i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/jLx5V/8/

Comment: @user2930185: By "initially define" do you mean does the `function resize() { /* ... */ }` need to be above where it's used? The answer is no: In JavaScript, a function *declaration* is processed before any step-by-step code in that same scope is run. So even though textually it's below the first line of code within the DOM ready handler, it happens beforehand. A function *expression* (`var f = function() { /* ... */ };`) is **not** done first, it's done when the code reaches that point in the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Jsfiddle loads the result in an iframe.

In this case `$(window).width()` gets the size of the iframe, not the actual window you see.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be binding to window resize not just on dom load...

```
$(function () {
  "use strict";
  $(window).resize(function (event) {
    if ($(window).width() >= 600) {
        $("section").hide();
    } else {
        $("section").show();
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/jLx5V/5/

Answer (score 0):

To complement the javascript-based answers, I would like to point out that this particular behavior can be implemented easily with media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    section {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jLx5V/10/ (try resizing the output pane)